# DataContext.CreateDatabase() says file already exists - but it doesn't

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, exception

This might be a Windows 7 issue, but calling

```
using (var context = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    if (!context.DatabaseExists())
    {
        context.CreateDatabase();
    }
}
```

Results in the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was
>   unhandled   Message=Database
>   'C:\Temp\SmallBusinessManager.mdf'
>   already exists. Choose a different
>   database name.   Source=.Net SqlClient
>   Data Provider   ErrorCode=-2146232060 
>   Class=16   LineNumber=1   Number=1801 
>   Procedure=""
>   Server=\.\pipe\952FCA9D-B4B6-4C\tsql\query
>   State=3   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean
>   sendToPipe)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteCommand(String
>   command)
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.CreateDatabase()
>          at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.CreateDatabase()

However I've deleted the database files.  What could be causing this?  Are the files really there but invisible somehow?  Something to do with junctions?

Comment: My code used to work and then started producing this same error - maybe a system update or something. Regardless, I found a solution to my expression of this message and posted it below as an answer in case it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and you'll be able to see the file io operations and why they fail. I find that this is often the best and quickest way to get to the root of the problem. It's an excellent utility.

Comment: +1. ProcMon is the first line of defense in obscure file and registry issues.

Answer (score 4):

### Tracking the Error

So I too have been trying to create a file-based database (named **C:\y\bjdatamig\IntermediateData.mdf** ) by running the `DataContext.CreateDatabase()` command and got the same error.

I'm on Vista SP2 with SQLExpress 2008 & VS2008, and used Process Monitor as [Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81769) suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796013/datacontext-createdatabase-says-file-already-exists-but-it-doesnt/2796022#2796022) here.  That led me to see SQL Server was writing to its error.log file which in turn revealed the following block of relevant info (entirety provided here in case anybody else sees something useful among the messages):

```
2010-06-23 17:04:10.50 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:10.50 Server      Detected 2 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:10.55 Server      Perfmon counters for resource governor pools and groups failed to initialize and are disabled.
2010-06-23 17:04:10.55 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:10.65 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000003 Active CPU mask: 0x00000003. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:10.69 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2010-06-23 17:04:10.79 spid7s      1 transactions rolled forward in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:10.91 spid7s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:10.91 spid7s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:11.12 spid7s      Error: 5598, Severity: 16, State: 2.
2010-06-23 17:04:11.12 spid7s      FILESTREAM feature is not supported on user instances.
2010-06-23 17:04:11.12 spid7s      FILESTREAM: effective level = 0, configured level = 0, file system access share name = 'SQLEXPRESS'.
2010-06-23 17:04:11.25 spid7s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2010-06-23 17:04:11.31 spid7s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2010-06-23 17:04:11.33 spid7s      The resource database build version is 10.00.2531. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:11.90 spid9s      Starting up database 'model'.
2010-06-23 17:04:11.91 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\95B6C915-3DB7-46\tsql\query ].
2010-06-23 17:04:11.94 Server      Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL Server. If you want to use a dedicated administrator connection, restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:11.95 spid7s      Server name is 'JOHN-W500\95B6C915-3DB7-46'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:12.22 spid7s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2010-06-23 17:04:12.27 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Error: 0x5, state: 4. Failure to register an SPN may cause integrated authentication to fall back to NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies.
2010-06-23 17:04:12.27 Server      SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:12.60 spid9s      Clearing tempdb database.
2010-06-23 17:04:15.49 spid9s      Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2010-06-23 17:04:16.27 spid12s     The Service Broker protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
2010-06-23 17:04:16.27 spid12s     The Database Mirroring protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
2010-06-23 17:04:16.36 spid12s     Service Broker manager has started.
2010-06-23 17:04:16.37 spid7s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2010-06-23 17:04:17.84 Logon       Error: 15350, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2010-06-23 17:04:17.84 Logon       An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\y\bjdatamig\IntermediateData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
2010-06-23 17:31:29.89 Logon       Error: 15350, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2010-06-23 17:31:29.89 Logon       An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\y\bjdatamig\IntermediateData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
2010-06-23 17:33:07.09 Logon       Error: 15350, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2010-06-23 17:33:07.09 Logon       An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\y\bjdatamig\IntermediateData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
2010-06-23 17:49:53.53 Logon       Error: 15350, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2010-06-23 17:49:53.53 Logon       An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\y\bjdatamig\IntermediateData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
2010-06-23 18:01:02.74 Logon       Error: 15350, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2010-06-23 18:01:02.74 Logon       An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\y\bjdatamig\IntermediateData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
2010-06-23 18:02:50.92 Logon       Error: 15350, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2010-06-23 18:02:50.92 Logon       An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\y\bjdatamig\IntermediateData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
2010-06-23 18:04:06.31 Logon       Error: 15350, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2010-06-23 18:04:06.31 Logon       An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\y\bjdatamig\IntermediateData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
2010-06-23 18:06:41.22 Logon       Error: 15350, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2010-06-23 18:06:41.22 Logon       An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\y\bjdatamig\IntermediateData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

My SQL Log file is at:

```
C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS\error.log
```

Importantly, for my situation, it indicates user instances do not support the "feature",  seemingly about streaming a file, and of course *CreateDatabase* is trying to write to the file system  ...

```
2010-06-23 17:04:11.12 spid7s      Error: 5598, Severity: 16, State: 2.
2010-06-23 17:04:11.12 spid7s      FILESTREAM feature is not supported on user instances.
```

... also my Connection string in APP.CONFIG specifies a "User Instance" ...

```
<add connectionString="Data Source=JOHN-W500\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\y\bjdatamig\IntermediateData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" name="IntermediateData" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

### Solution

I changed my connection string from

```
;Integrated Security=True;
```

to

```
;Integrated Security=False;
```

The database was created on the file system.

Why did I not have to change the "User Instance" option? Well, I'm unsure. In fact before I started getting this err the code worked, but I haven't tried it in a month - my speculation is maybe a system update or change to SQL Server caused it.  So although fixed, it's still a bit of a mystery.

Comment: Good effort in the investigative analysis!

Comment: Except it broke down (not a natural flow) in the solution; regardless it might help people trace a similar path to find a solution on their own system.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete the following folder and restart your machine in order to delete old User Instances. If get an error claiming the files are in use, you can "Close Handle" them by [Process Explorer](http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/ProcessExplorer.zip).

For XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS
```

For Vista:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS
```

For technical details about user instances read article titled "SQL Server 2005 Express Edition User Instances".