# Cannot create database file programmatically (SQL Server 2008 R2 Express)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-express

I'm trying to create a database with LINQ to SQL programmatically.

I tried (following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)):

```
MySQLSvrDb db = new MySQLSvrDb(@"c:\mydb.mdf");
if (!db.DatabaseExists())
{
    db.CreateDatabase();
}
```

But I get a SQLException "A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

However, for unit tests I created a database the following way (making sure I have a empty db for every test):

```
MySQLSvrDb db = new MySQLSvrDb(@"C:\testdb.mdf");
if (db.DatabaseExists())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Deleting old database...");
    db.DeleteDatabase();
}
db.CreateDatabase();
```

This works fine. My problem is I don't see a difference to the first approach. The problem is maybe somehow related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796013/datacontext-createdatabase-says-file-already-exists-but-it-doesnt), but the suggested solutions didn't work.

Any hints?

**EDIT**

If I just skip the DatabaseExists() step it works, but I need to check, if there's already a Db.

Comment: What's the difference between `factory.CreateDatabase()` and `db.CreateDatabase()`?

Comment: Should be db.CreateDatabase() of course :). EDITED

Comment: What context is the first piece of code running in? Is it asp.net (MVC?), and if so, is it running under Web Dev, IIS, IIS express?

Comment: Right now, it's just a local C# application

Comment: @Simon - hmm, I guess that rules out most permission issues (I'm also assuming that "C:\mydb.mdf" is a placeholder for the real path - I wouldn't recommend creating DBs in the root of the C drive)

Comment: Right now for test, the DBs are actually created in the root of C.

Answer (score 0):

How to: Dynamically Create a Database (LINQ to SQL)

[How to create DB in Linq to sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420.aspx)

Did you try deleting the first created DB first? and  run the method again?

Why you create Database locally,do you still attached it using sql server? 
You can use sql lite or sql server ce DB instead.

Regards!

Comment: Unfortunately this helps not at all, because I already stated in my posting that I tried it the way described in this Howto. BTW: your link is broken